# Center Across Selection - Button

Tags: microsoft-excel, ribbon

Is there a button in Excel (365) for Center Across Selection which one can add to the ribbon?
Can't find it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such entry in the "Customize the Quick Access Toolbar" dialog,
so you need to create this entry, like this:

- Select a single cell that is *not set with Center Across Selection*
- Start recording a macro by selecting *View > Macros > Record Macro*
- In the dialog, enter a macro name without spaces
  (example `CenterAcrossSelection` stored in the "Personal Macro Workbook"
- Click OK
- Open the Format Cells dialog via *Home > Format > Format Cells*
- In the dialog, in the Alignment tab, select "Center Across Selection"
- Click OK
- Stop the macro recorder via *View > Macros > Stop Recording*
- Select the little drop-down on the right side of the
  Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) and select "More Commands"
- In the dialog, select Macros from the "Choose commands from" drop-down,
  select your new macro, `CenterAcrossSelection` and click the Add button
- You may click the "Modify" button to customize the icon
- Close the Excel program itself, answering Save
- You can run the macro anytime by clicking the new QAT icon or by
  using the related Alt keyboard shortcut.

For more information with screenshots see :
[Center Across Selection QAT](https://www.excel-university.com/center-across-selection-qat/).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if there is no custom button available, one can use this macro and store it in Personal.XLSB

If one records the macro there is other format which will applied also, which might not be desired.

```
Sub CenterAcrossSelection()
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    Exit Sub
Errorhandler:
End Sub
```